# Dgrid update data store

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using [DGRID](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) to display data. I am aware i can query records in the store using store.query and insert records into the store using store.put and so on however i would like to do an update of the store. How can i update a record in the store?

I would prefer updating the memory store and then push that back into the database instead of updating the database first and then refreshing the memory store.

**Data**

```
 var data = [
            { id:"1", idType: "Passport", idNumber: "12121545WWW" },
            { id:"2",idType: "Drivers Permit", idNumber: "11212154515 FF"},
            { id:"3",idType: "Electoral Identification", idNumber: "425123123121"}
        ];
```

**Functions**

***Add data***

```
Store.put({id: enteredId, idNumber:enteredIdNumber,idType:enteredIdType})
```

***Query data***

```
Store.query({idType: enteredIdType})
```

***Update data*** - i am confused how this is done

```
Store.update({idNumber:enteredIdNumber,idType:enteredIdType})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about the dojo/store API.

- `store.add(item)` is used to add new items
- `store.put(item)` is used to update items, but can often also be used to add new ones with a specific ID
- `store.remove(id)` is used to delete items

If you wrap your store with `dojo/store/Observable`, e.g. `new Observable(new Memory({ data: ... }))`, then the grid will update automatically when `add` / `put` / `remove` are called.

See the [dojo/store documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store.html) for more information.

If you are wondering how to update records via the grid itself, have a look at the [editor column plugin](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/editor).

Comment: can you assist with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564146/dojo-dgrid-databinding

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an example of what your store structure is like? Normally if your store identifier is your "id", putting it again will just update the row. After putting new data, you can just call on grid.refresh() and it should update your table.